# How does $x^2+y^2+xy=\frac12$ become the ellipse $\frac{X^2}{1/3}+\frac{Y^2}{1}=1$?

Tags: vector-analysis

In the problem, I need to find the curve of the intersection of the plane $x+y+z=1$ and the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$.

I can visualise that the intersection would be an ellipse and when I substitute on equation into the other, I obtain $x^2+y^2+xy=1/2$. However, I don't understand what this equation represents since it's not equation for an ellipse.

In the solutions, $x^2+y^2+xy=1/2$ becomes the ellipse
$\dfrac{X^2}{1/3}+\dfrac{Y^2}{1}=1$, which I'm having trouble understanding where it comes from.

What does $x^2+y^2+xy=1/2$ represent? and how we find the ellipse equation from that?

Any help is very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need parantheses btw.

Comment: Let $X=x/\sqrt{2}, Y=x/\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}y$

Comment: Check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4681228/715008) answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does this equation $x^2+y^2+xy=1/2$ represent an ellipse?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3615117/how-does-this-equation-x2y2xy-1-2-represent-an-ellipse) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24x%5E2%2Bxy%2By%5E2%3D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%243X%5E2%2BY%5E2%3D1%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aellipse&p=1). Note that your $X^2/(1/3)+Y^2/(1)=1$ is considered the "standard" form, with this shown in [answer #1](/a/3615138) & [answer #2](/a/3615127) of this proposed duplicate question.

Comment: Essentially you take the equation of the rotated ellipse and reconstruct the original ellipse, accounting for long axis to be horizontal and finding a principal angle (positive less than $2\pi$) $\theta$. The angle solves by forcing the coefficient of xy to be zero.

$$\begin{align}x_r^2+y_r^2+x_ry_r=2\\ \Leftrightarrow (x\cos\theta-y\sin\theta)^2+(x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta)^2+ (x\cos\theta-y\sin\theta) (x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta)=2\\ \Leftrightarrow \frac {x^2}{\frac 13}+\frac{y^2}1=1\end{align}$$. There is also a formula for calculating the angle straight off  coefficients.

Comment: There’s a mistake in the comment above: the first two equations the right side should be $\frac 12$, mistakenly is 2.

Comment: An intersection of a plane and a sphere -- if exists -- is always a circle. Probably you wrongly set the problem.

Comment: Please do not use tags that are irrelevant and inappropriate.

Comment: The curve is a circle. Do you really want to project it and get an ellipse?

Comment: Geogebra3d parametrizes the intersection $\langle x+y+z-1, x^2+y^2+z^2-1\rangle$ as the circle $(\frac13-\frac1{\sqrt3}\cos{t}+\frac13\sin{t},\frac13+\frac1{\sqrt3}\cos{t}+\frac13\sin{t},\frac13-\frac23\sin{t}).$